# Need help iterating tests on a large list of elements

Tags: html, css, cypress

I am currently trying to find a way to iterate tests on a large list of elements. The elements are all 'li' and are cards/tiles with buttons and text displayed in an 'ul' (unordered list) grid.

Ideally, I need to be able to target each element in order and perform some steps and assertions on them.

I have the following written which doesn't work but it's as close as I can get using the cy.each() command:

```
cy.get('.ul_element')
should('have.length', X)
.each((list) => {
cy.wrap(list).should('have.attr', 'X')
})
```

I would love to be able to make assertions and also select buttons on each element one after the other.

Here is the list:

[image]

and one of li elements expanded:

[image]

If anyone cold help me get close that would be very much appreciated.

Cheers.

UPDATED:

After using cypher's comment I'm really close to what I need to do - I currently have the following iterating through each card and asserting that buttons are present on each card:

it('Each Card has an "i", "Download" and "More Actions" button', () => {

```
    cy.get('[href="/x/y"] > .w-full').click()
    cy.wait(2000)
    cy.get('.auto-rows-fr > li')
    .should('have.length', 25)
    .each((list) => {
    cy.wrap(list).children('[class="relative rounded-lg card-container-inner h-full"]')
    .children('[class="relative z-0 flex flex-col h-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg card-front"]')
    .children('[class="flex flex-col justify-between flex-1 py-4 px-3 bg-white"]')
    .children('[class="m-0 pt-3"]')
    .children('[class="flex   justify-between"]').then(($btnBar) => {

    cy.wrap($btnBar).children('[title="More information"]').should('exist')
    cy.wrap($btnBar).children('[title="Download file"]').should('exist')
    cy.wrap($btnBar).children('[title="More options"]').should('exist')
    })
    
    
    
    })
});
```

I'm wondering if anyone knows how I would add a loop to this to enable me to click the individual buttons on one card before progressing to the next?

Comment: What issues are you having using the `.each()`?

Comment: Please add your html.

Comment: @AlapanDas I've added a link to a screenshot of the ul containing the li elements. I hope this makes sense as I'm new to working with html. Thanks.

Comment: @agoff so when I am trying to make assertions on the elements, it will test them all at once instead of in order and can cause cypress to crash as there are so many items.

Comment: Expand one of the `li` elements.

Comment: @AlapanDas I've added another link showing as much expanded as would fit. Let me know if that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing something in the selector. The way you do it, only iterates through each `ul` element. But you want it to iterate through each `li`element.

Try this for example:

```js
cy.get('.auto-rows-fr > li')
should('have.length', X)
.each((list) => {
cy.wrap(list).should('have.attr', 'X')
})
```

Comment: Thanks!! I used this and I'm getting close to what I need to do - I've added and updated section above if you could take a look at it I'd be eternally grateful.